# Select row where specific column has the highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see in the title, I need SQL query(MySql) to get row where specific column has the greatest value.

So I need to select row where `fav` has the highest value. That means its bigger than `def`,`rop`,`tip` and `uio`. In my case it should be row number 3. Bellow you can see one part of my sql table

I tried with this query but it seems to me very slow(0,009s) on 20 records, any other query takes max. 0,003s.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE fav>def AND fav>rop AND fav>tip AND fav>uio
```

Is there any better way for this? Thank you

**table**

```css
table td {padding:4px 8px}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>id</td><td>fav</td><td>def</td><td>rop</td><td>tip</td><td>uio</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>293</td><td>331</td><td>773</td><td>225</td><td>982</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td><td>123</td><td>533</td><td>224</td><td>111</td><td>632</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:lightblue">
<td>3</td><td>982</td><td>398</td><td>182</td><td>321</td><td>222</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td><td>343</td><td>765</td><td>700</td><td>901</td><td>300</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to do a full table scan for this type of query.  However, performance on 20 rows should not be taken as a guid for overall performance.  Databases are designed to handle much larger queries and 0.009 seconds is pretty small on human timeframes.

I don't think there is a way around it.

You can simplify the query using `greatest()`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE fav > GREATEST(def, rop, tip, uio);
```

If I had to guess, this would slightly slow down the query.